# Find the area of an infinitesimal elliptical ring.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have an ellipse given by,
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=c$$
and another ellipse that is infinitesimally bigger than the previous ellipse, i.e.
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=c+dc$$
I want to find the area enclosed by the ring from $x$ to $x+dx$ but I don't know how. Please don't solve the question, just point me in the right direction, I want to solve it myself. Here is a picture of what I want to do.
[image]

Comment: Can you solve the problem for the special case of a unit circle? If so, the result follows by applying the change-of-variables formula to a particularly simple coordinate change.

Comment: No. I don't see it through, I can't solve for the unit circle.

Comment: If we consider the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ small, we can see that the radius of the circle satisfies $r^2 = 1 + \epsilon$, so $r = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$. Thus, its area is $\pi \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)\right)^2 = \pi + \pi \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$, and the area of the annulus is $\pi \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: A uniform thickening of a noncircular ellipse is not itself an ellipse.

Comment: I am not thickening the ellipse. I am increasing the value of c to c+dc. That is an ellipse, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the ellipse can be derived from a circle by means of a dilation along $y$ of ratio $b/a$,
we can find the desired area by considering a circular ring with radii $a\sqrt c$ and $a\sqrt{c+dc}$ and then multiplying the result by $b/a$. A $y$ section of such a circular ring at $x$ has a width 
$$
dy=\sqrt{a^2(c+dc)-x^2}-\sqrt{a^2c-x^2}={1\over2}
{a^2\over \sqrt{a^2c-x^2}}dc
$$ 
to first order in $dc$. The area, to first order, is formed by two parallelograms of basis $dy$ and height $dx$, so we have
in the end for the desired area in the ellipse:
$$
dA = {b\over a}\,2\,dy\,dx={ab\over \sqrt{a^2c-x^2}}dc\,dx.
$$
Notice that by integrating the above for $-a\sqrt c<x<a\sqrt c$ one gets, as expected, the annulus area $\pi ab\,dc$.

Comment: That the area of the ring, but how do I find the area of the hatched region i.e. between $x$ and $x+dx$?

Comment: I hadn't read that comment in the picture: you'd better point that out in the main text of your question.

Comment: Just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a\sqrt{c}\cos(\varphi)$, $y=b\sqrt{c}\sin(\varphi)$. The Jacobian is
$$J=det\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}a\cos(\varphi) & -b\sqrt{c}\sin(\varphi) \\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}a\sin(\varphi) & b\sqrt{c}\cos(\varphi)
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{ab}{2}
$$
Hence $dS=\frac{ab}{2}dcd\varphi$, integrating over angle we get 
$$dS=ab\pi{dc}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that you just scaled up both the major and minor axes by a common factor $ \sqrt c$

You want to look at

$$   (\sqrt c\, y )\ d (\sqrt c  x ) -  y\ dx = (c-1) y\ dx . $$